# How to get the Stack-trace of golang in the Crashlytics

Tags: android, go, stack-trace, crashlytics, google-fabric

Our's app is a Android app, which has a JNI writed by golang. And we use the Fabric Crashlytics to track carshes.

But, we can not get the Stack-trace information in the Crashlytics, after a crash happened in the JNI. In the Java, We can get it.

In the Object-C for iOS app, we can upload the dSYM file to map the functions. But where can I do it with Golang?

Does the Fabric support it?

Now, in the Crashlytics, we can see below only:

```
Crashed: Thread
0  libc.so                        0xf6f4c778 (Missing)
1  libc.so                        0xf6f26791 (Missing)
2  libc.so                        0xf6f23933 (Missing)
3  (Missing)                      0x15c791e6 (Missing)
4  libgojni.so                    0xdddd910e (Missing)
5  libc.so                        0xf6f214ee (Missing)
6  (Missing)                      0x15c791e6 (Missing)
7  libgojni.so                    0xde00a8de (Missing)
8  libgojni.so                    0xde00a93e (Missing)
9  libgojni.so                    0xdddd8ed6 (Missing)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have been resolved this issue.

The background:

> We build a Android app, it has a JNI writed by go, which is build by gomobile.
> We use the Fabric Crashlytics to monitor the crash information.
> But in the Crashlytics, we could not see the full stack trace information which occurred in the JNI.

The Solution is:

> At the first, please check your NDK version, it must be `r17c` or more.
>
> Add a param `--work` in the gomobile command, like `gomobile bind --work YOUR-SOURCE-CODE-PATH WORK=TEMP-PATH`.
>
> After build successful, move the all of files in the `jniLibs` to `YOUR-PROJECT-PATH/app/obj`.
>
> At the last, do the steps list in Fabric docs.

Hope our experiences can save your time :-)